# pymysql: How to format types on query?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

I'm trying to insert rows on a MySQL table using pymysql (Python 3), the relevant code is the following.

```
def saveLogs(DbConnection, tableName, results):
    for row in results:
        formatStrings = ",".join(["?"]*len(row))
        sql = "INSERT INTO %s VALUES (%s);"%(tableName,formatStrings)
        DbConnection.cursor().execute(sql, tuple(row))
    DbConnection.commit()
```

I'm using `"?"` for the types, but I get the error `not all arguments converted during string formatting`. `row` is a list composed of `string`s, `int`s and `datetime.datetime`. I guess the issue is the `"?"` but I have checked the PEP 249 and it's still not clear to me how should I do it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use string formatting for the table name only (though make sure you trust the source or have a proper validation in place). For everything else, use *query parameters*:

```
def saveLogs(DbConnection, tableName, results):
    cursor = DbConnection.cursor()
    sql = "INSERT INTO {0} VALUES (%s, %s, %s)".format(tableName)
    for row in results:
        cursor.execute(sql, row)
    DbConnection.commit()
```

There is also that [`executemany()` method](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html):

```
def saveLogs(DbConnection, tableName, results):
    cursor = DbConnection.cursor()
    cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO {0} VALUES (%s, %s, %s)".format(tableName), results)
    DbConnection.commit()
```

Comment: "%s" is not string? how to handle dates and integers?

Comment: @lithiium the mysql driver itself should handle the type conversions when you make parameterized queries.